# Swift Array firstIndex & Equatable

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following class in Swift

```swift
public class ItemModel:Identifiable, Equatable, Loadable {

    public static func == (lhs: ItemModel, rhs: ItemModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    public var id: UUID

    public init() {
        self.id = UUID()
    }

}
```

And then I have subclass

```swift
public class SubItemModel: ItemModel {


}
```

I have an array *layerItems* of type [SubItemModel]. When I test the following code

```swift
public func removeItem(_ item:SubItemModel) -> Bool {

    //This line fails despite $0 and item having same id, why?

    if let index = layerItems.firstIndex(where: {$0 === item}) {

        item.cleanup()
        layerItems.remove(at: index)

        return true
    }
}

return false
}
```

It returns *false* because firstIndex(where:...) returns nil. Why is it so despite the item with given id being present in the array?

Comment: `===` and `==` are two different operators.

Comment: @vadian Oops, I failed to look at it closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vadian notes, `===` is not the equality operator. It is the "same instance" operator. Two class instances that are "equal" (according to Equatable) will fail `===` if they are not the same object.

Given your description, you should be able to use `firstIndex(of: item)` rather than `firstIndex(where:)`. But also be very careful of implementing `==` using only a mutable ID. This allows for two objects to have different properties, but still compare "equal" according to Equatable (and therefore interchangeable in all contexts). You generally should not do partial property checking in `==` for mutable objects or any situation where two objects might differ despite having the same identifer.